# Using Regular Expressions in Netbeans 8.2 "find & replace"

Tags: regex, netbeans, find-replace

I am using NetBeans 8.2. I am working in the code editor window and trying to use regex in combination with the NetBeans find/replace feature. I have the regex button turned on.

I am trying this 
[image]

on this code

```
    specStripWidthUpper: $("#uniflytebundle_quoteitem_QuoteRing_specStripWidthUpper"),
    specStripWidthLower: $("#uniflytebundle_quoteitem_QuoteRing_specStripWidthLower"),
```

The result I would like would take 1st Category found in find regex

```
specStripWidthUpper
```

and repeat it on other side of colon ":" like

```
specStripWidthUpper:specStripWidthUpper
```

instead it replaces the selection with $1. looking like

```
    specStripWidthUpper:$1,
    specStripWidthLower:$1,
```

Is there a NetBeans setting to run regex for the replace input window or am I doing something incorrect?

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netbeans (8.2?) does not like the lookarounds. I do not know if this is a new thing but you can get around it with a simplified pattern.

However, your pattern does not capture the part you want to repeat, i.e. `specStripWidthUpper` (you can see this when you toggle the Select option).

Try it like this:

```
(\w+)(?:\:)(.*),
$1:$1
```

You might be required to anchor the query to avoid false positives.